# Map with timed/transient entries - memory not an issue

Tags: java, dictionary, transient

I'm trying to create a map in which the entries time out and get removed after a certain time period.

Basically, `<K, V> Map.put(K key, V value, long **time**)` - the entry will be put in the map instantly and will expire after **time** (ms). I do not need to recover the removed entry at any point in the future but I would like to make sure it's no longer in the map.

For example: `map.put("foo", "bar", 60l * 1000l)` will let this key-value pair live in the map for a minute (60long and 1000long).

Attempt: use a ConcurentMap and implement `Map.put(K key, V value, long **time**)` via the following:
1. call `super.put(key, value)`
2. create a thread that sleeps for **time** (ms)
3. call `remove(key)` to remove the entry.

Question: please comment/let me know whether this is a good idea in terms of thread-safety, consistency or any flaws in my attempt. If you think there's a better way to accomplish this, please provide any advice.

Edit: Thanks for the replies, *memory is not the issue here*, I really only care about the short life-span of the entries. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the time an essential part of the problem you're solving? Or is it an implementation detail? If the problem you're solving is one of memory use, two other possibilities spring to mind:

- An LRU Map. There are a number of these on the web.
- A Map backed by WeakReference or SoftReference objects, which allow the GC to collect those items.

**EDIT**

In that case, there are some existing implementations that might save you some time. For instance:

- [TimedHashMap](http://reteptools.kenai.com/api/retepTools/SNAPSHOT/uk/org/retep/util/collections/TimedHashMap.html) (one implementation)
- [TimedHashMap](http://code.google.com/p/modex44107gr1/source/browse/trunk/Routage/src/Utils/TimedHashMap.java?r=578) (another implementation)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm only concerned with the time here, memory isn't an issue.

Comment: +1 for quick Edit. I want the entries to be alive for different amounts of time but the second implementation with Timer is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this because of some memory issue (the map is a temporal cache), you should probably consider using soft references ([documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)).

Comment: I wasn't able to find how soft references allow me to time the objects, can you be a little more specific? Thanks.

Comment: There's no real connection.  He's just saying that there's often a connection between a map used as a cache and soft references.  The temporal bit can be ignored.  Guava's MapMaker has options for creating soft references, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) - it's a collection library from Google.  In particular, you want to look at CacheBuilder and its computing maps.  One of its features is "time-based expiration of entries, measured since last access or last write", sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

(Edited to talk about CacheBuilder; it's new since I posted this and is more relevant to the question)

Comment: Thanks for the Guava reference.